# no option of booting from pen drive

Tags: boot, usb-drive

I made a full ubuntu installation on my pendrive, but now when I try to boot Ubuntu through my pendrive on some other system(already installed with ubuntu), there is no option of booting from pendrive.

Comment: Is BIOS configured to boot from the pendrive? Is the system BIOS or UEFI?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if you use some kind of extension for USB ports like an express card to get USB 3.0 on your laptop or something like this it can be the your computer is unable to boot from these ports. *Use the ones built into your computer.*

Most modern computers will allow you to boot from USB. You can find this option in your BIOS or UEFI settings. Look out for "booting options" or "boot order" and move USB to the top.

If there is no USB option there, you *simply can't boot from USB on your computer*. Move the DVD boot option to the top and burn Ubuntu to a DVD.

Comment: also, many times, you can press one of the F buttons to allow a boot menu at startup separate from bios options

Comment: Edited (and as it now is an excellent answer): upvoted!  ;-)